# mouse wheel scroll DIV element

Tags: javascript, html, scroll, mouseevent

If I have two `DIV` elements :

```
#my-div1 {
  position:absolute; /* relative or fixed  */
  z-index:20;
}
#my-div2 {
  position:absolute;
  z-index:10;
  height:500px;
  overflow:scroll;
}
```

Is it possible to scroll `#my-div2` when mouse cursor is over `#my-div1`, using javascript?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [.mouseover()](http://api.jquery.com/mouseover/) in combination with a scrolling library to execute the scrolling javascript:

```
$('#my-div1').mouseover(function() {
  //use Scroll library
});
```

A good library is [ScrollTo](http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/ScrollTo).